# To create array from 1 php variable Why out put not same array?

Tags: php, arrays

To create array from 1 php variable Why out put not same array ?

in this code i create array using php variable

```
<?PHP
$xxx = "'Free', 'Include', 'Offer', 'Provide'";
$xxx_array = array($xxx);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($xxx_array); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and echo is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Free', 'Include', 'Offer', 'Provide'
)
```

how to echo like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Free
    [1] => Include
    [2] => Offer
    [3] => Provide
)
```

Comment: $array = array(0 => 'Free', 1 => 'Include', 2 => 'Offer', 3 => 'Provide');  print_r($array);

Comment: @Priyajain that is a very tedious way of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$xxx = "'Free', 'Include', 'Offer', 'Provide'";
// Split by ","
$separatedValues = explode(',', $xxx);
// Remove the single quotation marks
for($i = 0; $i < count($separatedValues); ++$i) {
  $separatedValues[$i] = str_replace("'", '', $separatedValues[$i]);
}
var_dump($separatedValues);
?>
```

It is all about the `explode()` (http://de.php.net/explode) function.

Comment: This still won't preserve the same semantics - The values will be quoted.

Comment: Oh. I've overlooked the quotation marks to be also removed.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. The below code accomplishes what you ask.

```
<?PHP
    $xxx = "'Free', 'Include', 'Offer', 'Provide'";
    $xxx_array = array(explode(",", $xxx);
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($xxx_array); 
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mimic actually creating the array (and not having the values quoted within the array), use this:

```
$xxx_array = array_map( function( $el) { return trim( $el, "' "); }, explode(',', $xxx));
```

This trims the `'` and spaces from the beginning and ends of the elements after converting the string to an array.